# Фильтрация DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Есть таблица в нее загружаються данные из SQL
Мне нужно отфильтровать DataGrid по данным из TextBox.
Формирование таблицы.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="phonesGrid" Margin="10" BorderBrush="Black">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" Header="Название государства" Width="135"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Company}" Header="Столица" Width="120"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Население" Width="110"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Square}" Header="Площадь(км²)" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date}" Header="Дата" Width="130"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**C#**

```
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Phones";
        phonesTable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            // установка команды на добавление для вызова хранимой процедуры
            adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertPhone", connection);
            adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Title"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@company", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Company"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Price"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Square", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Square"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.Date, 0, "Date"));
            SqlParameter parameter = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id");
            parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(phonesTable);
            phonesGrid.ItemsSource = phonesTable.DefaultView;
            DataTable costomers = ds.Tables[0];
        }
```

Comment: я не работаю с `WPF`, но могу предположить, что отвечающим может понадобиться этот самый `TextBox` и код формирующий `SQL`.

Comment: я бы вам сказал phonesGrid.ItemsSource= from DataRow myRow in dt.Rows
                          where (string)myRow["Name"] == "Test2"
                          select myRow; отсеять сам массив и бросить это дело НО. Так поступать не надо!) Посмотрите гайд по MVVM, там будет простой пример с TextBox и binding data, получается вы должны отправить в модель текст, который изменит модель и вернет во вью измененное состояние. Так будет замечательно :)

Comment: Title - если это список, то применить Title.Find(t = > t.Title = textbox.text); код для пример, не ругайтесь.